# How do i use time.sleep , and do something different each second

Tags: python, time, process, pyqt5

I am making a PyQt5 splash screen in PyQt that creates a countdown within a splash picture, but the script isn't behaving right and it has different result each time.

```
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont, QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QSplashScreen
import os
import sys
import time
from time import sleep



count = [1,2,3,4,5]

def Splash(self):
    app.processEvents()
    splash = QtWidgets.QSplashScreen(QtGui.QPixmap("22.png"))
    font = splash.font()
    font.setPixelSize(16)
    font.setWeight(QFont.Bold)
    splash.setFont(font)
    #splash.showMessage(str(count[0]), QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter | QtCore.Qt.AlignBottom, QtCore.Qt.white )
    #splash.show()
    for i in range(0, 10):
        time.sleep(1)
        splash = QtWidgets.QSplashScreen(QtGui.QPixmap("22.png"))
        splash.showMessage(str(count[0]), QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter | QtCore.Qt.AlignBottom, QtCore.Qt.white)
        QtWidgets.QApplication.processEvents()
        splash.show()
        time.sleep(1)
        splash = QtWidgets.QSplashScreen(QtGui.QPixmap("22.png"))
        splash.showMessage(str(count[1]), QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter | QtCore.Qt.AlignBottom, QtCore.Qt.white)
        QtWidgets.QApplication.processEvents()
        splash.show()
        time.sleep(1)
        splash = QtWidgets.QSplashScreen(QtGui.QPixmap("22.png"))
        splash.showMessage(str(count[2]), QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter | QtCore.Qt.AlignBottom, QtCore.Qt.white)
        QtWidgets.QApplication.processEvents()
        splash.show()
        time.sleep(1)
        splash = QtWidgets.QSplashScreen(QtGui.QPixmap("22.png"))
        splash.showMessage(str(count[3]), QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter | QtCore.Qt.AlignBottom, QtCore.Qt.white)
        QtWidgets.QApplication.processEvents()
        splash.show()
        time.sleep(1)
        splash = QtWidgets.QSplashScreen(QtGui.QPixmap("22.png"))
        splash.showMessage(str(count[4]), QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter | QtCore.Qt.AlignBottom, QtCore.Qt.white)
        QtWidgets.QApplication.processEvents()
        splash.show()
```

In short terms: How do I use time.sleep(), and every second do something different. Any suggestions?

```
import time


for i in range(0, 10):
    time.sleep(1)
    print "1"
    time.sleep(1)
    print "2"
    time.sleep(1)
    print "3"
    time.sleep(1)
    print "4"
    time.sleep(1)
    print "5"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can

```
import time

for i in range(0, 10):
    time.sleep(0)
    print i
```

Or in your example...

```
for i in range(0, 10):
    time.sleep(1)
    splash = QtWidgets.QSplashScreen(QtGui.QPixmap("22.png"))
    splash.showMessage(str(count[i]), QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter | QtCore.Qt.AlignBottom, QtCore.Qt.white)
    QtWidgets.QApplication.processEvents()
    splash.show()
```

You can either use a conditional statement to loop only until i <= 4

```
for i in range(0, 10):
    time.sleep(1)
    splash = QtWidgets.QSplashScreen(QtGui.QPixmap("22.png"))
    if i <= 4:
        splash.showMessage(str(count[i]), QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter | QtCore.Qt.AlignBottom, QtCore.Qt.white)
    else:
        QtWidgets.QApplication.processEvents()
    splash.show()
```

Comment: the answer made by dot.PY

did the trick thx

You can either use a conditional statement to loop only until i <= 4

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you want it to do?

```
import time
for i in range(10):
    time.sleep(1)
    print(i)
    time.sleep(1)
    print("New command; Iteration:", i)
    time.sleep(1)
    print("New new command; Iteration:", i)
```

Comment: it does not.I wanna call a splash screen each second having a different number hardprinted into it each second.
yor code call 0 to 9 all in once